# Turning dynamically created texboxes' values into JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, dynamic

I am trying to create an application that will allow users to add a textbox and then submit the data in the textbox to a JSON file. I have tried using Ajax, but am unsure how it works with dynamically created objects. Any help in any language would be appreciated.

Here is the code to create the textbox:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                 var counter = 2;
                 $("#addButton").click(function () {
                if(counter>1000000){
                        alert("Exceeded Text Box Limit");
                        return false;
                }   
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                      '<input type="text" class="title" name="title[]' + counter + 
                      '" id="title' + counter + '" value="" >');

 );   
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#Spacer");
                counter++;
 });
```

Also, is it possible to remove this data if the user removes a text box? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might Get u started

once You have created the TextBox u have to attach a click event handler to the created textbox by using

```
$( "container" ).on( "click", "#Yourcontrol", function() {
 var TextBoxVal = $(this).val();
//write logic to send Data 
});
```

you can serialize the data using form.serilize()[Serilize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method and send it to the  server side.

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as , , and : $( "input,
>   textarea, select" ).serialize();